# ASP.NET MVC2 + Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership

I would like to create user in my user table when new user have just registered to ASP.NET MVC application (I use the default ASP.NET MVC logging system - Membership. I want to get the new registered user's guid and create user in my database which will have the same guid and keep there different data like name surname etc. How can I do it? How can I just get the registered person ID? I was trying to do it in

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model) function in AccountController
```

but I do not know how to get the just registered user's guid this is not working:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email);

        if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

            //string guid = Helpers.getLoggedUserGuid(); //return null

           //if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { } // return false
           //if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {} // return false
           //Membership.getUser() // return null
           //The most funny is that after this redirection below the user is logged in - I do not understand it
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountValidation.ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;
    return View(model);
}
```

Is any possibility to get this guid in this function? (I know that I can get userName and so on but I can not understand why I can not get this guid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Guid from `MembershipUser`:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(model.Username);
var guid = (Guid) user.ProviderUserKey;
```

MSDN:

> The ProviderUserKey property exposes
>   the identifier from the membership
>   data source typed as object. The type
>   of the identifier depends on the
>   MembershipProvider or the
>   MembershipUser. In the case of the
>   SqlMembershipProvider, the
>   ProviderUserKey can be cast as a Guid,
>   since the SqlMembershipProvider stores
>   the user identifier as a
>   UniqueIdentifier.

Comment: I thought the same but in this function it is empty yet and I can not understand why as redirecting is later and after redirecting there is a value in Membership.GetUser(), it looks like it is updating this Membership while it is redirecting...

Comment: GetUser() returns currently logged in user. Since the user is not yet created he is not logged in. You could try with Membership.GetUser(model.Username);

Comment: Wooow, Thank you for this comment frennky - it solved out my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can't get that value in the method you are trying. unless you use the `Membership.GetUser()`

What you **should** do is:

create a common controller, for example:

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    public MembershipUser _user = null;
    public MembershipUser User {
        if(_user == null) _user = Membership.GetUser(model.Username);
        return _user;
    }
    public GUID UserGuid {
        get { return (Guid)User.ProviderUserKey;; }
    }
}
```

and then, instead of having your Controllers derivate from `Controller` make them inherit from your new custom Controller

```
public class SalesController : MainController
```

and in any method you need, you just call `this.User` to hold the `MembershipUser` or `this.UserGuid` to get the User Id.